# Find and set only first duplicated value remaining duplicates set to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could someone help me to make a query that sets the value to field but only once per duplicated record?
I do have some duplicated rows and I need a column that stores the value of my transaction only once. I did tried but without good effect, right now I'm stuck with a query like this.

```
SELECT         JOURNALNUMBER, SUBLEDGERVOUCHER, ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT, MAINACCOUNTVALUE, 
                    ITEMID,  QTY, INVENTTRANSID, 
                         (SELECT        count(journalnumber)
                           FROM            TestGeneralTransY AS tab
                           WHERE        (TestGeneralTransY.JOURNALNUMBER = JOURNALNUMBER) AND (TestGeneralTransY.ITEMID = ITEMID)
                           AND (TestGeneralTransY.mainaccountvalue = mainaccountvalue) AND (TestGeneralTransY.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT = ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT)
                           ) AS MInAmount
FROM            TestGeneralTransY
```

I want that the MinAmount would show only one valu per transaction like in PAF-004644308 I would need one row with value -79,5 and the second with 0. I do need this because I need to do sum calculations and with duplicated values its not possible for me.

| JOURNALNUMBER | SUBLEDGERVOUCHER | ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT | MAINACCOUNTVALUE | ITEMID | QTY INVENTTRANSID | MInAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PAF-004644305 | WZ-0187132 | -39.750000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -186.000000 PT020719031 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004644308 | WZ-0187135 | -79.500000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 2 |  |  |
| PAF-004644308 | WZ-0187135 | -79.500000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 2 |  |  |
| PAF-004644324 | WZ-0187146 | -397.490000 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -10.000000 | PT022252398 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004647078 | WZ-0187322 | -10573.990000 | 3110001 MPL-FOR-0227 | -4500.000000 | PT022149061 1 |  |
| PAF-004654294 | FSL22000020 397.490000 | 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -10.000000 | PT022252398 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004654296 | FSL22000021 79.500000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 2 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004654296 | FSL22000021 79.500000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 2 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004654297 | FSL22000022 39.750000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -186.000000 PT020719031 1 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004660123 | FSL22000026 10573.990000 | 3110001 MPL-FOR-0227 | -4500.000000 | PT022149061 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004667259 | WZ-0188549 | -357.740000 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -9.000000 | PT022252398 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004667260 | WZ-0188562 | -119.250000 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004667260 | WZ-0188562 | -119.250000 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004667260 | WZ-0188562 | -119.250000 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004673442 | WZ-0189010 | -73.770000 | 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -1.000000 | PT022252398 1 |  |
| PAF-004673524 | WZ-0189011 | -39.750000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 1 |  |  |
| PAF-004686484 | FSL22000103 39.750000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0036 | -260.000000 PT021519260 1 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004686612 | FSL22000104 431.510000 | 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -9.000000 | PT022252398 2 |  |  |
| PAF-004686612 | FSL22000104 431.510000 | 3110001 MPA-PAL-0010 | -1.000000 | PT022252398 2 |  |  |
| PAF-004686824 | FSL22000106 119.250000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004686824 | FSL22000106 119.250000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |
| PAF-004686824 | FSL22000106 119.250000 | 3110001 MPL-WST-0044 | -260.000000 PT020719031 3 |  |  |  |

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` and a `CASE` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to numerate your items, and then `CASE` to return `ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT` only for first one.

```sql
select
    JOURNALNUMBER,
    SUBLEDGERVOUCHER,
    case
        when rn = 1 then ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT
        else 0
    end ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT,
    MAINACCOUNTVALUE,
    ITEMID,
    QTY,
    INVENTTRANSID
from
    (
        select
            JOURNALNUMBER,
            SUBLEDGERVOUCHER,
            ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT,
            MAINACCOUNTVALUE,
            ITEMID,
            QTY,
            INVENTTRANSID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY JOURNALNUMBER
                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
            ) rn
        from
            TestGeneralTransY
    )
```

Please check if `OVER` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()` makes sense for your data.

Comment: Every column name together with rn in first select gives me an error invalid column name

Comment: @Tweene, sorry missed `FROM` and parentheses. Corrected answer.

Comment: It's okay, even I didn't noticed the lost "from" anywany it still misses a table prefix. The query works like charm so thank you :)